# Service Fabric Actors or Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-functions, service-fabric-actor

I am trying to understand differences between a FaaS in Azure and Actors in Service Fabric. To me both almost do same and are serverless. The only difference is Actor is single threaded. Is there a good explanation to distiguish these two?

Answer (score 1):

Service Fabric Actor actual is a stateful service so service fabric will maintain the state for you. Over simplify example: You have a method to add 1 into a variable x start at 0. You call that method twice. When you get x you will get 2 with stateful service.

Whereas Azure function is not. Similar with example above you will get 1 even you call it twice as your state is not maintained.You can actually sharing state as describe here. However it is possible doesnt mean you should do it :-)
https://markheath.net/post/sharing-state-between-azure-functions.

Answer (score 1):

My rough notes on this.

ASE = App Service Environ,
CP = Consumption Plan for functions, 
SF = Service Fabric

Configuration

- Functions - PaaS model, no real OS considerations
- SF - Must provision up containers.  Closer to IaaS

Computing

- Functions in Consumption Plan – shared space
- Functions in ASE – dedicated execution zone
- SF Dedicated scale set

Costs

- Functions in CP – most likely cheaper – pay per use
- Functions in ASE – on par or more expensive than SF
- SF – moderate pricing, requires 5 node min

Developer Experience

- Functions - fairly easy
- SF - fairly Complicated

Service Ramp Up

- Functions CP - easy, no min bar for config.  Just deploy function.
- Functions ASE – takes a bit. Full ASE environ.
- SF – takes a bit.  5 node minimum

Scaling

- Functions - Automatic Consumption and ASE
- SF - Supported

Dialog welcome...